# JPA - Retrieving data from database table wrt Foreign key -

Tags: java, database, list, jpa

I am trying to retrieve data from a table which has a foreign key, "reg_no". And the foreign key is not unique, it can be duplicated.

Now I want to retrieve the data from this table using this foreign key. I will provide a "reg_no" and the Java Persistence API will retrieve a list of the result set from the table wrt to "reg_no" provided.

Please enlighten me how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, using JPQL:

```
String queryString = "SELECT t FROM YourTable t " +
                     "WHERE reg_no = :regNo";
Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(queryString); 
query.setParameter("regNo", regNoValue);
return query.getResultList();
```

Comment: thank to you too..! It doesn't work, I resolved this problem, I can provide you a link to the solution if u want..! Thanks again..! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
List results = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Vehicle v WHERE reg_no = :reg_no").setParameter("reg_no", new String("0000")).getResultList;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help mate.. But unfortunately, it doesn't work..! Anyways I resolved this problem, I appreciate your help.. If u wanna know the solution, i can provide a link to the solution..!

Comment: That would be interesting and useful for anyone else searching with the same question, please do!